# How do I declare a var from current form when you have multiple forms on page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

```
    $('#submit').click(function () {        

    //Get the data from all the fields
    var name = $('input[name=name]');

    //organize the data properly
    var data = 'name=' + name.val();        

    //start the ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: "process.php", 
        type: "GET",
        data: data,     
        cache: false,
        //success
        success: function (html) {              
            //if process.php returned 1/true (send mail success)
            if (html==1) {                  
                //hide the form
                $('.form').fadeOut('slow');                 

                $('.done').fadeIn('slow');

            //if process.php returned 0/false
            } else alert('error');              
        }       
    });

    //cancel the submit button default behaviours
    return false;
}); 


<form id="form1" method="post" action="process.php">
<div class="element">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="text" />
</div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>

<form id="form2" method="post" action="process.php">
<div class="element">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="text" />
</div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

I have two forms and would like to submit one of them when hitting the submit button. Is there a way to automatically declare the var "name" BASED ON the form submitted (form1 or form2)? I want to avoid having duplicate routines for each form if I can have just one.

Option 1 (I know this works - BUT it's not very "smart"):

var name = $('#form1 input[name=name]');

var name = $('#form2 input[name=name]');

Option 2 (need help with):

var name = $('***the-current-form-submitted***.input[name=name]');

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't have two submit buttons with the same ID. That's invalid markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change your logic slightly to have a `submit()` handler for each form, which both then pass along to a single processing function which completes your AJAX request. This will also remove the need to have the same `Id` on two elements which is invalid (Your `#submit` buttons).

```
$("#form1, #form2").submit(function(e) {
    completeForm($(this));
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the form submitting
});

function completeForm($form) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "process.php", 
        type: "GET",
        data: 'name=' + $('input[name=name]', $form).val(),     
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {              
            //if process.php returned 1/true (send mail success)
            if (html == 1) {   
                $form.fadeOut('slow');
                $('.done').fadeIn('slow');
            } 
            else 
                alert('error');              
        }       
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(this).parents("form").find("input[name=name]")
```

or

```
$('input[name=name]',$(this).parents("form"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find the form from the submit button, like this:

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    var name = $(this).closest('form').find('input[name=name]');
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Karmran:s answer will do it or refactor to

```
$('form').submit(function() {
//do your formstuff
return false;});
```

note: id:s should be unique, #submit is in DOM twice.